# How do I create a substack with code?

Tags: livecode

How do I create a named substack with a background by livecode?

The livecode dictionary has an entry

`create stack`

with examples

`create stack "Test"`
or

`create stack field 3 with background "Standard Navigation"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single command to create a substack. instead you need to create a mainstack, and then change it's `mainstack` property to some other stack to make it a substack of that one. for example:

```
create stack "my new stack"
set the mainstack of "my new stack" to "some existing stack"
```

see also the `mainstack` property, the `mainstacks` function and the `mainstackChanged` message in the dictionary.

There is another way to achieve your goal, by setting the mainstack of the templatestack (see the `templateStack` object in the dictionary):

```
set the mainStack of the templateStack to "some existing stack"
create stack "my new stack"
```

Answer (score 2):

As Bjoernke said.

Note also that you can use the inspector as well. There is a pullDown menu that can set the "mainstacK" property of any stack to any open stack. Sometimes when dealing with a number of stacks in a project, this can be useful.

Craig Newman